# Executing tests in another build.gradle project

Tags: rest, testing, jenkins, gradle

I am finishing a Continuous Integration system with Jenkins and Gradle for a REST service. It will build the App and dependent sub-libraries, build a Docker, start main docker and secondary ones (database, ...) all in Gradle.
As it is a REST service I have a separate project that executes the REST tests completely from outside my project just as it is a REST client, and works ok...

Once my project is built and everything running I need to execute the build in the other project (which is just for tests) as a subproject, and wether it passes or not the tests I want to continue the main script as Dockers need to be stopped and deleted. What is the best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a task with **type: GradleBuild** in parameter

Example:

```
task buildAnotherProjectTask(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = '../pathToBuildFileInTheOtherProject/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['build'] // You can run any task like that
    tasks = ['test'] 
}
```

and to run it u can use the following command

> gradle buildAnotherProjectTask

This is worked with me when i tried it.

Hope my answer will help :)